# sqlite orderby not working in android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

i have a problem with this code:

```
Cursor c = db.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Rankings WHERE " + DataBaseAdapter.R_RID + " = " + strID +
            " ORDER BY " + DataBaseAdapter.R_POINT + " DESC", null);
```

my code works correctly until the numbers goes up to 10
Look at the Result:

8

7

6

12

11

is there anyone that help me to get something like this:

 12 
 11 
 10 
 8 
 7  and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type specified for the field `DataBaseAdapter.R_RID` is a `STRING`, so the ordering is not working correctly, change the type of your field to `INTEGER`

You will do this as an option:

```
 " ORDER BY CAST(" + DataBaseAdapter.R_POINT + " AS INTEGER) DESC"
```

Comment: Yes i Got the answer Tanx.

Comment: in insert on database that was integer but in create Table was Text

Comment: Yes thats what a i said, you must change the type in your table to INTEGER.

Comment: Can't let a sister down.  +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you declared your R_POINT table as a string instead of numeric (so you're getting a lexical sort). Change the column to be NUMERIC (and make sure you insert numbers, not string) and the ordering should work.

Comment: Yea in insert on database that was integer but in creat Table was Text
Tanx Chris